# Check if height has changed from certain amount

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a number has increased or decreased to a certain amount from another.

For Example:

```
Let a = 20;
Let b = 20;
```

If `b` has increased by 5 from what `a` is, return `true`.

If `b` has decreased by 5 from what `a` is, return `true`.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
var lastHeightSize = document.body.scrollHeight;

function checkBodySizeChange () {
    // instead of checking if lastHeightSize is not equal to document.body.scrollheight,
    // check if document.body.scrollheight has increased or decreased by 20
    const heightChanged = lastHeightSize !== document.body.scrollHeight;
    if (heightChanged) {
        trigger(document.body, 'sizechange');
        lastHeightSize = document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(checkBodySizeChange);
}
```

Comment: `Math.abs(oldV-newV)>changedLimit`

Comment: This works! Thanks so much for the quick response rlemon!

Comment: I added it as an answer. trying to get out of the habit of answering in comments :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the updated code to reflect rlemons answer.

```
  var lastHeightSize = document.body.scrollHeight;
  function checkBodySizeChange () {
    const heightChanged = Math.abs(lastHeightSize - document.body.scrollHeight) > 120;
    if (heightChanged) {
      trigger(document.body, 'sizechange');
      lastHeightSize = document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(checkBodySizeChange);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Math.abs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)

```
Math.abs(oldV-newV)>changedLimit
```

Then you can see if it's changed positive or negative by any amount.